# How to remove a level in file structure in Windows 10

Tags: filesystems

I have searched, and found some old questions and answers, but nothing has worked for me.  I have drive with several TB of photos (avid amateur photographer for decades).  The directory structure has some directories set up how I want them, and for many thousands of directories it is not.  The "bad" ones are all of this structure:

```
\top level directory\photos\*.jpg
\top level directory\photos\raw\*.nef
\top level directory\photos\final\*.* (mostly .jpg files)
```

I want to get rid of the \photos level and move everything up, but retaining the sub-directory structure.  I know I can do it manually in file explorer, but there are several thousand of the top level directories.  (These are in turn stored in higher level directories, mostly year by year and month by month.)

Is there an easy way to do this using PowerShell or command?  I also use JPsoft Take Command, but that doesn't seem to help in this case.

Thanks

A further explanation was requested, so here goes:

Ok, Here's the REAL structure:

```
P:\Photographs\2000\(01) January\lots of folders here\photos\*.*
P:\Photographs\2000\(01) January\lots of folders here\photos\raw\*.*
P:\Photographs\2000\(01) January\lots of folders here\photos\corrected\*.*
P:\Photographs\2000\(02) February\lots of folders here\photos\*.*
...  (similar to above, but in February)
P:\Photographs\2001\(01) January\lots of folders here\photos\*.*
... (similar, but a different year)
```

I have photos (scanned) that go back to 1969, so there are 500+ year/month directories.  Some months there are no photos, some there are individual shoots with 1000+ photos (sporting events), and in the film days there are directories for each 36 shot roll of film, usually I'm guessing on the month/year if they were scanned from negatives, slides have a date they were processed on each slide.

I messed up, and sometimes the structure is the way I want it (i.e. without that extra level with no content other than sub directories, sometimes not.  I can move all the good or bad "trees" to a separate high-level folder, or even to a separate drive, it's the mass renaming in a safe and consistent way I'm looking for.

The total collection right now is ~200,000 photos and 4TB, which I have on mirrored 6TB drives, going to move to a FreeNAS system soon.

Comment: Definitely doable with Powershell. I've actually done something similar (but more complex) recently. Don't have time to write it as answer right now, but if you don't have an answer in a few days, give me a mention and I will give you an answer then. Actually, for you it is waaay easier. Just one for loop and a move command using the .PSPath and .PSParentPath.

Comment: Thanks, I'll do some research.  I'm just getting started with PowerShell, I'm sure it can be done that way.  My days writing lots of scripts is way in the past, on technology long in disuse (VAX and Alpha OpenVMS).

Comment: Can you edit the question and provide more details about the top level folder thingy with different folders before it? It is going to be necessary because we need to dynamically traverse these folders.

Comment: Ok, Here's the REAL structure:

Comment: I think something went wrong posting the real structure. Also, please edit your question, don't put it in the comments, other users won't usually read them when posting an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Windows `robocopy` command. But need to exclude the `photos` folder from being moved. Also there is Total Commander or any similar file operating app which you could use. TC also has option to change many filenames with one click - accessible by Ctrl+M. Totally free is Double Commander.

It is worth to mention that having many folders and/or files in root folder of the drive is not seen good by many operating systems.

Comment: Thanks.  I don't have these in root folder, the actual structure is something like: P:\Photographs\2017\(07) July\"top level directory"\photos\...  It's that photos level I want to kill.  I did a mass scanning project and ended up with the extra level, and I have annual directories from 1973 to 2018, as well as some subject directories for special projects, so the number gets large.

Comment: Still you can do this using TC and its option to select files by `wildcards`. Moving all folders from one folder to folder two levels up is also available in Windows Explorer - default window for files. You can use two explorer windows for that - source and target.

Comment: Using windows explorer makes me REALLY nervous - I've had it crash in the middle of a process so many times, and then you have stuff partially moved and it can be hard to unwind.  Of course, I will copy the whole drive before starting onto a spare 6TB spindle.

Comment: Crashing explorer is a reason to test RAM. It is not normal for explorer to crash. Depends on the error message.